# RPi0 W can't connect wlan0 wireless

Tags: pi-zero-w

About 2 years ago as my first foray in SBC's I setup a RPi0 W as wireless print server which worked very well. Fast forward to a few days ago and I needed to change the network connection and I can't find the password anywhere. After trying various ways to work around this I gave up and decided to start from scratch. I used the RPi imager to load the recommended Bullseye based non GUI system. After that entering the SSID and PW in raspi-config I'd get an error "error running option s1 wireless lan" and no matter what I've tried the wifi will not connect to the network.
After hours of searching and not finding an answer I took some advice and changed to the newer bookworm version but still have the same issue. Everything I've tried shows wlan0 "disconnected", the network, locale and other info looks appropriate.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first 3 sentences (which if they were to be read) should be in a paragraph but as you apparently started again is completely irrelevant.

Comment: What you ACTUALLY did after that is unclear but AFAIK installing Bookworm on a Pi Zero is not recommended (at least until Raspberry Pi Ltd. get it working). It doesn't work on a normal Pi with 1GB no chance on 500MB.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by flashing the OS with the Raspberry Pi Imager but not entering the user name/PW and network info at that time. After configuring it with Raspi-config the wifi worked as it should.

Coincidently I've seen that other people have had the same problem.